# Editing raw CSS stylesheet without SASS

Tags: css, sass, stylesheet

I've only started using SASS and it's helping me greatly with CSS coding. My only issue is what's the best practice when somebody, who doesn't use SASS, edits the raw stylesheet. The new codes on the raw stylesheet are not integrated with SASS.

The solution I can think of is to manually find the "new codes" and re-organize it using SASS. But is there a more automated / faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to have your CSS stylesheet update your Sass file. I am not sure there would be a good way to implement that either. Sass isn't incredibly opinionated, which would make it difficult. Honestly, my personal opinion is Sass is something that is simple enough that someone who is comfortable with CSS should be able to pick it up very quickly. CodeSchool has a great introductory course to it that should get your teammate up to speed quickly.

The problem with editing the raw stylesheet is that the raw stylesheet will likely just get overridden as soon as you make changes to the Sass file and you recompile your CSS. Most people writing with precompiled CSS generally have either a watch set on the file either using their terminal or an app like CodeKit. Which facilitates writing your Sass, but also facilitates overwriting your the CSS file. (which is by design)

The bottom line is, your teammate probably should just take a couple of hours to study Sass. It is also notable that CSS is valid Sass.